# How To Save Image into Sdcard From Url android

Tags: java, android

i am new in android. i want to save image from url into SDcard.

```
 File direct = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
               + "/.imgapp");

    if (!direct.exists()) {
           direct.mkdirs();
       }
       Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
       int d = c.get(Calendar.DATE);
       int d1 = c.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1;


       File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
               + "/.imgapp/"+d+""+d1+".png" );
       if (!file.exists()) {
           URL url = new URL ("file://some/path/anImage.png");
           InputStream input = url.openStream();

        try {

          OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream (Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
               + "/.imgapp/"+d+""+d1+".png");

       try {
          byte[] buffer = new byte[aReasonableSize];
          int bytesRead = 0;

        while ((bytesRead = input.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) >= 0) {
              output.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                }
           } finally { output.close(); }
          } finally { input.close(); }

       }else{
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

       }
```

manifest file

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

i try This Code But App Stop and Crash please Help Me.
i want download image onCreate when user open App.

Comment: what is error? install logcat to see error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally Done!!.

```
 DownloadManager mgr = (DownloadManager) this.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);

           String uRl = "http://bitsparrow.altervista.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/5.jpg";
        Uri downloadUri = Uri.parse(uRl);
           DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(
                   downloadUri);

           request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(
                   DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI
                           | DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE)
                   .setAllowedOverRoaming(false).setTitle("Demo")
                   .setDescription("Something useful. No, really.")
                   .setDestinationInExternalPublicDir("/.appimg", "test.jpg");

           mgr.enqueue(request);
```

This Work For me..!